# The recent change in suggested edit approval needs to be updated in all sites' "Edit questions and answers" privilege info page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, help-center, privileges-page

With follow up of [this post from Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349613), in all the Stack Exchange site's  **Edit Questions And Answers** privilege page the term **"except on Stack Overflow where three votes are required."** is used under the **Reviewing suggested edits** section.

Recently [the change made to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349118) that the approval votes for the suggested edit is reduced to two from three votes.

So in all the `https://sitename.com/help/privileges/edit` page the content for the recent change can be update in the **Reviewing suggested edits** section.

> Two votes in either direction will finalize the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and [the edit privilege page in the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) now reads that two votes are needed, as shown in the screenshot

[image: screenshot of the edit privilege page]